# select items from ng-option in scope variable when using array of strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas

I want to select item from list on the double-click ,but the problem is I am using array of string instead of json object.Below is ng-option html tag.

```
<select multiple id="selectFeature" multiple class="form-control" 
    ng-model="features" 
    ng-required="true"
    ng-options="select as feature for feature in allfeatures"  
    ng-dblclick="moveSelectedValues(features)">
</select>
```

how can I get the selected value in scope variable?

Comment: Can you put some sample code

Comment: <select multiple id="selectFeature" ng-model="features" ng-required="true" multiple class="form-control"  ng-options="select as feature for feature in allfeatures "  ng-dblclick="moveSelectedValues(features)" ></select>

Comment: I want value of selected item in scope variable i.e. $scope.selectedvalue=$scope.features.value; but its failing